# Является ли установка переменной после Thread.Sleep(1000) производительной?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Часто использую подобные функции:

```
bool lol = true; 
new Thread(() => {Thread.Sleep(1000); lol = false;});
```

Просто нужно через некоторое время изменить значение переменной. Если данный способ плохой, то пожалуйста подскажите вариант получше.

Comment: без контекста нельзя ничего сказать

Comment: Не является. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Используйте для таких целей `Timer`

Comment: Нутром чую, что эта булева переменная используется как флаг в ещё одном потоке для его остановки/запуска. Если да, то ваш код полностью неверен и подлежит полному переписыванию.

Comment: Это очень плохое решение, вы лочите поток, который мог бы использоваться для других нужд, используйте  System.Threding.Timer.

Comment: bool lol = true; Task.Run(delegate {Task.Delay(500); lol = false; });

Comment: данный вариант получше?