# Изменение значения из задержкой

Tags: c#, многопоточность

```
private async Task SendWithDelay(int delay, Action action)
            {
                await Task.Delay(delay);
                action();
            }
```

Использую данную функцию для того чтобы поменять значение флага. То есть имею переменную которая принимает true or false. И нужно через некоторое время поменять значение. Является ли данный метод приоритетным? Я не использую таймер, потому-что данная функция используется очень часто.

Comment: Практически [тот же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/952003/213987) вы уже спрашивали ранее вокруг одной и той же темы, зачем плодить несколько, если вы всё равно не отвечаете на уточняющие вопросы?

Comment: я ответил, мне ничего не ответили.

Comment: На такого вида вопрос вы опять не сможете получить ответ. Почему? Да, потому что этот метод (в две строчки длиной) ни о чем не говорит. Важен контекст в котором он используется. Вы читали комментарий Alexander Petrov на свой предыдущий вопрос на эту тему? Что скажите? Зачем вам булевый флаг потребен?